# Trying to pass in an array to justGage

Tags: javascript, justgage

I'm using JustGage Javascript Plugin to create a dynamic gauge. I want to pass in an array to this gauge and have it display those values. So far, I'm only able to get it to display random integers using `getRandomInt()`.

Here's the relevant js part of the code:

```
<script src="justgage-1.2.2/justgage.js"></script>
<script src="justgage-1.2.2/raphael-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

        var g1 = new JustGage({
            id: 'g1',
            value: getRandomInt(0, 100),
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            pointer: true,
            gaugeWidthScale: 0.6,
            customSectors: [{
                color: '#ff0000',
                lo: 50,
                hi: 100
            }, {
                color: '#00ff00',
                lo: 0,
                hi: 50
            }],
            counter: true
        });

        setInterval(function() {
            g1.refresh(getRandomInt(0, 100));
        }, 2000)
    });
    </script>
```

I'm wondering why something like

```
var num= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

var i = 0; 

setInterval(function() {

          document.innerHTML = num[i++]; 
          if (i == num.length) i = 0; 
                 }, 1000);
```

Can't be used instead of the `getRandomInt()` function.

Since this can't be seen on jfiddle or codepen, here's the plugin's site that shows some demo charts: http://justgage.com/ Instead of having to hit a refresh button, it refreshes on it's own.

Thought it would be more productive to ask here while I still try to work things out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man that plugin has lousy docs...

Seems like you're not far off with what you want to do - in your setInterval you're going to want to do something like this, with the key part being the `g1.refresh(val)` with the new value of your gauge.

```
var i = 0,
    num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

setInterval(function() {
    if (i >= num.length) i = 0;
    g1.refresh(num[i++]);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: That's close too! issue is that it's stuck on 1 for whatever reason

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch that... long day. Thanks for the help!